# row of characters in R function output

Tags: r, character, output

I am writing a function that extracts information from models, and I am wanting to separate parts of the output, like the `mtable` in the `memisc` package, a row of hyphens or dashes between one block of output like parameter estimates and another block like information criteria or separating different models. so if I have a two matrices and I want to separate them by a dashed line like

so if i have two matrices combined they would be

```
structure(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
```

but separate they would be

```
structure(c(1, 3, 2, 4), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
structure(c(1, 3, 2, 4), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```

and wanting them to show up as matrices but how do i add a row of characters to it instead of just doing it manually and guessing on how many to put there without the quotes or the line numbers?

I have tried `paste` command, `format`, `cat`, `rep("=")` and I know that will kind of work but don't know how to control the width. I know I am kind of vague and apologize for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: my apologies on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowSums(nchar(x)) + ncol(x)` should give you a good enough approximation to figure out how wide your row of `=` should be.

An example:

```
x <- matrix(c(10, 2, 123, 4), ncol = 2)
rowSums(nchar(x)) + ncol(x) - 1
# [1] 6 3
max(rowSums(nchar(x)) + ncol(x) - 1)
# [1] 6
```

For figuring this out across multiple matrices, I suppose you could calculate the width across multiple matrices with something like this:

```
max(vapply(list(x, y), function(i) {
  max(rowSums(nchar(i)) + ncol(i))
}, 1))
```

where `list(x, y)` is a list of a matrix named "x" and one named "y".

Comment: thanks, this along with finding another post helped me, found a similar post on the side.

Comment: @JPK, cool. You can also look at the code of the functions you refer to and figure out how they calculated the width. The `by` function in base R, for instance, uses the `width` "option" as a basis for how many dashes it should print.

Comment: i know how to look at code usually but i couldnt find all of it but did find some more of it by looking at a related post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046682/creating-nice-looking-output?rq=1) sorry for the superfluous question here, i didnt find that response until i asked it.